# Protect excel sheet but allow table to be modified

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet locked so that the user cannot modify the cell values, but so I can run VBA macros to do calculations. My code goes like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Protect "Password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Next
Other_function()
End Sub
```

This works fine, preventing the user from modifying cells, but allowing this example to work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Worksheets(1).Range("A20").Value = "AAA"
End Sub
```

However, when I try to add rows to a table, I get a 1004 error:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set ws = Worksheets("SecondSheet")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("TableName")
Dim newrow As ListRow
Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add
With newrow
    .Range(1) = onevalue
    .Range(2) = twovalue
    .Range(3) = threevalue
    ...
End With
```

How can I tell Excel that I need to put new rows in this table without unprotecting the whole thing every time?

Comment: Did you try adding line ws.Unprotect "Password" before your last part of the code ?

Comment: That would work, but if for any reason the code crashes the sheet will be left unprotected. I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: @Variax That'd be kind to accept my answer if it helped. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot accept only VBA to do it, you have to unprotect the sheet before doing your operations and reprotecting it after.

You can allow adding/removing columns in a protected sheet with **AllowInsertingColumns** or **AllowDeletingColumns** but if you do so, you will accept the script AND the user to insert or remove columns.

[Source for AllowInsertingColumns and AllowDeletingColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, protecting a worksheet disallows adding or deleting rows to/from a table. You'll have to unprotect the sheet.